# How to set cart template based on product type?

Tags: magento

I have a new product type and when on cart page, I need to show a different cart.phtml for that custom product type. If I set like this, all product types will use this new cart.phtml.

```
<checkout_cart_index>
   <reference name="checkout.cart">
      <action method="setTemplate">
         <template>mymodule/checkout/cart.phtml</template>
      </action>
   </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

However, if I use this, it doesn't work.

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_custom module="catalog">
   <reference name="checkout.cart">
      <action method="setTemplate">
         <template>mymodule/checkout/cart.phtml</template>
      </action>
   </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_custom>
```

Is there any other way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle PRODUCT_TYPE_custom is used only on product page. What you can is to check in controller if your cart includes specific product and add custom layout handle which you can use in layout updates. You need to override checkout controller in this case.
Howewer controllers are not the best place to have a logic. So better solution is to use some event like *controller_action_layout_load_before* and in add this logic in observer observer:

```
$update = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate();
$update->addHandle('custom_checkout_handle_name');
```

Then add xml in your layout update:

```
<custom_checkout_handle_name>
    <reference name="checkout.cart">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>checkout/cart_alternative.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</custom_checkout_handle_name>
```

Of course it's not a complete solution but good direction for your next thoughts ;)

Comment: Creating a new handle is not a solution since this will screw up the whole cart especially if there are other products (with default product types) in the cart. The one that I observe is **checkout_cart_product_add_after**

Also, observing **controller_action_layout_load_before** is not a good idea (performance sake) since this will affect all pages, both frontend and backend.

Comment: So sorry that means I didn't understand your question clearly. I thought you need to update whole cart design in case if you have at least one specified product. IN this case my solution with handle works. Let me notice I suggest not replace handle but add additional one. Inside this additional handle you can make as many changes as you need (like <action method="setTemplate">...</action> for exact references you need). Also regarding performance - I believe just one if with addHandle call would not make any problems due to performance :) But you can chose any other event you wish.

Comment: Anyway I've updated solution with xml for layout update. That what I ment regarding the handler.